# Trying to use scanner in java to read just a stroke of the return key as an input?

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am making a program that will read user input and determine with an `if`/`else` condition what to do. If the user hits just enter and doesn't type anything else in, I want to loop something through the if. If anything else is typed as an input, the program should exit back to a different menu.
Here is what I have so far:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String choice = scnr.next();
if (choice.equals("")) { 
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

When I run through it, just pressing enter does not affect anything, it just makes the cursor advance to the next line in the console. However, when I type something in, the error part that sends it to the menu when anything else is typed in works just fine. I'm thinking I have to use something besides `scnr.next();` but I don't know what that would be.

This is for an entry level class, and it requires that we use the scanner utility and not something more advanced. Thanks in advance.

```
do
{   
    //string variable used to take scanner input when
    //looping generations
    String choice = "";
    printWorld( patternName, world, generationCounter);
    System.out.println("Options");
    System.out.println("(Enter): show next generation");
    System.out.println("end(Enter): end this simulation");
    System.out.print("Choice:");
    choice = scnr.nextLine();
    if (choice.length() == 0) {
        //used as a filler array when the method
        //next generation is called
        boolean newWorld[][] = new boolean [world.length][world[0].length];
        nextGeneration(world, newWorld);
        for (int i=0; i<newWorld.length;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<newWorld[0].length; j++){
                world [i][j] = newWorld[i][j];
            }
        }
        generationCounter++;
        System.out.println("went through");

    } else {
        generationKill = 1;
        generationCounter = 1;
    }
} while (generationKill !=1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `scnr.nextLine();` instead of `scnr.next();`

The reason for this is because of tokens. `next()`'s documentation says:

> public String next()
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

Token generally is separated by whitespaces ("\n", "\t", " ") and therefore will not recognize your "enter" or "\n" character as a token. Which is why it'll keep reading, thinking that you haven't entered any tokens.

`nextLine()` on the other hand will read until it finds a "\n" character. That means when you enter, it's reading in a "\n" character, thereby setting your `choice` to be `""`.

Comment: You should explain why `nextLine` works, but `next` does not.

Comment: Let me know if I missed anything in my explanation.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working when I hit enter, and now when I enter in something besides just hitting enter, that part won't work either. Literally the only thing I did was change .next() to .nextLine() and I have no clue as to why. @sparky

Comment: Can you update your code? Let me see if I can find out what's going on.

Comment: ` do
     { 
      //there would be a menu with options here //and other printed matter...
       choice = scnr.nextLine();
      if (choice.equals("")) { ...
       }                                                           else {
       generationKill = 1;
      }
     } while (generationKill !=1);`

Comment: No problem man, you can edit your post and attach it at the end.

Comment: So after it enters your `do while` loop, when you just click enter, it's not going into the if statement?

Comment: It's working for me...I just got rid of all the things dealing with `newWorld` stuff and it works properly. It might be within those logic so I would double check that actually.

Comment: yeah that definitely works, thank you, I will check my other stuff